# Animate matshow function in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a matrix which is time-depedent and I want to plot the evolution as an Animation.

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


n_frames = 3 #Numero de ficheros que hemos generado
data = np.empty(n_frames, dtype=object) #Almacena los datos

#Leer todos los datos
for k in range(n_frames):
    data[k] = np.loadtxt("frame"+str(k))


fig = plt.figure()
plot =plt.matshow(data[0])

def init():
    plot.set_data(data[0])
    return plot

def update(j):
    plot.set_data(data[j])
    return [plot]


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func = init, frames=n_frames, interval = 30, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

However, when I run it I always obtain the following error: `draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render`. I don't know where this error come from and no idea on how to solve it. 
I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429556/animate-quadratic-grid-changes-matshow) and also [this article](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/tag/matplotlib/) but still don't know why my code is not working.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close to a working solution. Either change

```
plot = plt.matshow(data[0])
```

to

```
plot = plt.matshow(data[0], fignum=0)
```

or use

```
plot = plt.imshow(data[0])
```

instead.

---

The problem with using `plt.matshow(data[0])` here is that it [creates a new figure](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2241) if the `fignum` parameter is left blank (i.e. equal to `None` by default). 
Since `fig = plt.figure()` is called and that `fig` is passed to `FuncAnimation`, you end up with two figures, one with the result of `plt.matshow`, and the other blank one being drawn on by `FuncAnimation`. The figure that `FuncAnimation` is drawing on does not find the initial draw, so it raises

```
AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render
```