# How to create a video from a 3d heat map in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3D numpy array x of size (100,64,64) where it contains 100 consecutive 64 by 64 2D array. I want to create a video of the heat maps of these 100 different matrices. How can I do this I python?

I know that I can create each heat map image by the following code:

```
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
c = axes.pcolormesh(x[i])
figure.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

where i is a number between 0 and 99. How can I create a video from these 100 consecutive images?

Comment: A simple way i can think of is save all the 100 as images. combine them to create a gif.

Comment: Thre are plenty of libraries you can do this like ffmpeg or even opencv.

Comment: @venky__ Thanks, that's a good idea. But maybe there exists a way to do it by code!

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος Could you please go more in detail? And examples?

Comment: @b.j  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429556/animate-quadratic-grid-changes-matshow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472017/how-to-animate-the-colorbar-in-matplotlib